# Cleaning tracked keyframes in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm new to After Effects and played with Mocha for After Effects a bit (which is v.easy to pick up) and was wondering: If I have a bunch of dense set of keyframes as a result of tracking, is there an After Effects option/script that can clean the data (reduce keyframes but maintain easing/timing) ? 
Is this possible ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select all the keyframes you want reducing and use the built-in plugin called 'smoother' which will convert your set of baked keyframes back into a bezier curve.

Comment: I'm trying to clean the camera keys (camera is imported from Blender).  This works for the "position" parameter but not for orientation.  Any solution that would work for *any* parameter ?

Comment: I assume you mean "smo**o**ther"? In any case, I can't find anything like that in AE CC 2018. Where do I need to look?

Comment: **Edit:** nvm, it's under "Window"